# Pass list in JPA named native query

Tags: jpa, orm, jpql, named-query

We want to pass list of strings into JPA named native query.How we can achieve this.it is throwing invalid query parameter exception.

Comment: Why a native query? Handling a list requires modifying the SQL to add in parameter binding for each list element, not something supported by the JPA specification. Any solution would be provider specific. JPQL queries though have much wider support for collection parameters.

Comment: We have a JPQL query with ids as a list like this, we are facing syntax error issue with that,hence tried native query.
select r.city,case when r.name='test' then 'T' else 'N' end from testable r where r.id in (:ids) group by r.city,case when r.name='test' then 'T' else 'N' end;. It is complaining about comma after r.city in group by clause.

Comment: That is likely the question you should be posting instead then. That Query doesn't look valid - try aliasing your initial case statement and using that within the order by clause.

Comment: I have earlier posted but did not get any response,hence tried with native query.Can you update this query so that it will work( I have added alias to case statement  as suggested)
 select r.city,case when r.name='test' then 'T' else 'N' end as 
 opt from testable r where r.id in (:ids) group by r.city,case when r.name='test' then 'T' else 'N' end;

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query(value = "select e from student so where so.name in ?1", nativeQuery = true)
List<Student> someFunName(List<String> stringList);
```

U can try something like this for a nativeQuery, for list of string as param.

(I just gave an example for Entity Student)

Comment: We are using openjpa Named native queries,Given solution is not for openjpa

Comment: can u show what u are using presently, we can tell what and where to change it. U can try **in** instead of equal to in the query and **.setParameter(1, list)**.

Comment: we are getting specified parameter of type java.util.arraylist is not a valid query parameter
Query looks like this-
select name,city from user where userid in (?);